# Django views and URl's

Tags: python, django

I'm having a problem with the way my URL's look in Django. I have a view like this:

```
def updatetext(request, fb_id):
    Account.objects.filter(id=fb_id).update(display_hashtag=request.POST['hashtag'])

    fb = get_object_or_404(Account, pk=fb_id)
    return render(request, 'myapp/account.html', {
        'success_message': "Success: Settings updated.",
        'user': fb
    })
```

When a user clicks on the URL to update the text they are then redirected to the account page but the URL then looks like 'account/updatetext/'. I would like it just be 'account/'.

How would I do this in Django. What would I use in place of render that would still allow me to pass request, 'success_message' and 'user' into the returned page but to not contain the 'updatetext' within the URL?

[edit]

The urls.py file looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^home/$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<fb_id>\d+)/$', views.account, name='account'),
    url(r'^(?P<fb_id>\d+)/updatetext/$', views.updatetext, name='updatetext'),
    url(r'^(?P<fb_id>\d+)/updatepages/$', views.updatepages, name='updatepages'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^admin/$', views.useradmin, name='admin'),
)
```

Comment: What does your `urls.py` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually redirect the user to '/account/'. Rather than returning a call to `render` you can do the following:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def updatetext(request, fb_id):
    Account.objects.filter(id=fb_id).update(display_hashtag=request.POST['hashtag'])

    fb = get_object_or_404(Account, pk=fb_id)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account', kwargs={"fb_id": fb_id}))
```

However, it would be better to pass in a call to `reverse` into the `HttpResponseRedirect` constructor, but since I don't know your urls.py I just wrote the relative url.

Comment: The url for the account/ page looks like this 'url(r'^(?P<fb_id>\d+)/$', views.account, name='account')' How would I pass the 'success_message' and 'user' to the page using HttpResponseRedirect?

Comment: I updated the answer to pass the fb_id into the reverse call which will generate the correct url. You'll need to pass the success_message via the ```request.session``` or you can use django's messages framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/messages/. I suppose a final, yet extremely hacky way of handling it would be to pass it as a query parameter in the URL to the view.

Comment: @user2547755 One more thing, always redirect a user after receiving a `POST` request. This prevents users from (mostly accidentally) sending a request twice when reloading the page, and prevents duplicate data or perceived errors when the data is initially saved correctly.

Comment: Thanks @schillingt. You have clarified this matter for me.